# Unable to scrape all the results from search page

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to retreive all the results from the following website by making a request as follows :

```
class MyPropertySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_property'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.myproperty.co.za/search?last=1y&coords%5Blat%5D=-33.2277918&coords%5Blng%5D=21.8568586&coords%5Bnw%5D%5Blat%5D=-30.4302599&coords%5Bnw%5D%5Blng%5D=17.7575637&coords%5Bse%5D%5Blat%5D=-47.1313489&coords%5Bse%5D%5Blng%5D=38.2216904&description=Western%20Cape%2C%20South%20Africa&status=For%20Sale',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {
            'authority': 'jf6e1ij07f.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
            'pragma': 'no-cache',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Mobile Safari/537.36',
            'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'origin': 'https://www.myproperty.co.za',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'referer': 'https://www.myproperty.co.za/',
            'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        }

        data = '{"clientOfficeId":[],"countryCode":"za","sortField":"distance","sortOrder":"asc","last":"0.5y","statuses":["For Sale","Pending Sale","Under Offer","Final Sale","Auction"],"coords":{"lat":"-33.9248685","lng":"18.4240553","nw":{"lat":"-33.47127","lng":"18.3074488"},"se":{"lat":"-34.3598061","lng":"19.00467"}},"radius":2500,"nearbySuburbs":true,"limit":210,"start":0}'

        response = requests.post('https://jf6e1ij07f.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/p/search', headers=headers,
                                 data=data)
```

However, I am only able to get 200 results from the page, even tho 1000+ is available on the given search page. I see that the data limit in the request is 210 and when I try to increase it does not change. I am not sure how to (or if it is possible?) to fix this?
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using scrapy I suggest you use `FormRequest` instead of the `requests` lib. You can do the same POST request with both. [Here is the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) if you want to read on this method.

---

This is the form data you are passing, it gives the server all the search parameters you are interested.

```
data = {
    "clientOfficeId": [],
    "countryCode":"za",
    "sortField":"distance",
    "sortOrder":"asc",
    "last":"0.5y",
    "statuses":["For Sale","Pending Sale","Under Offer","Final Sale","Auction"],
    "coords":{"lat":"-33.9248685","lng":"18.4240553",
    "nw":{"lat":"-33.47127","lng":"18.3074488"},
    "se":{"lat":"-34.3598061","lng":"19.00467"}},
    "radius":2500,
    "nearbySuburbs":True,
    "limit":210,
    "start":0
}
```

Since the server isn't willing to give you all the data at once (*I haven't tested, but you said that increasing limit didn't change the result*), it expects you to "paginate" through the data, just like you would do it in a website.

When you send the form above, it returns you 210 results, so the next time you call it you need to tell the server you want the **NEXT** 210 results, not the same you already received. For that you will use the `start` field in the form. In your next request use `"start":210` and keep adding up until the server start returning empty responses. (Usually the responses are not completely empty, but the field with results return empty)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Is there an efficient way to send multiple requests to the same URL and retrieve all this data in one JSON? @renatodvc

Comment: If the server limits 210 results, you won't get a JSON with more than that, no matter how you request it. You could send multiple requests and accumulate the responses, but the best approach here would be to have it request it recursively, each callback parsing the response, increasing the `start` by the previous offset and yielding a new request. If you need this data aggregated for some reason you can always write a [pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).